# Physics based trigonometry question

Tags: trigonometry, physics

I am working on solving the problem stated in this image:

[image]

I understand almost everything about this problem. I solved for the magnetic field along the axis of a circular loop, and now I need to integrate from Ө1 to Ө2.

The problem I am encountering is that I am not sure how to put dz in terms of dӨ. Here is how the example does it:

[image]

Can someone explain these steps to me? I pretty much understand every step here except for this one:

$$
\frac{d\theta}{\cos^2\theta} = -\frac a{z^2}\,dz
$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might consider reading all the answers (e.g., the ones that won't be posted until 45 minutes from now) before accepting one. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

$$ \tan \theta = \frac az$$

Now perform differentiation on both sides against some dummy variable $t$:

\begin{align} 
\frac{d}{dt}\tan\theta &= \frac{d\theta}{dt} \sec^2\theta \\
\frac{d}{dt}\frac az &= -\frac{dz}{dt} \frac{a}{z^2}.
\end{align}

"Eliminate" the $dt$ and use $\sec\theta=\frac1{\cos\theta}$.

$$\frac{d\theta}{\cos^2\theta} = -\frac{a}{z^2}dz.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\tan\theta = \frac a z \tag 1
$$
Consequently
$$
\frac 1 {\cos^2\theta} = \frac d {d\theta} \tan \theta = \underbrace{\frac d {d\theta} \frac a z = \frac{-a}{z^2}\,\frac{dz}{d\theta}}_{\text{chain rule}}
$$
$$
\frac{d\theta}{\cos^2\theta} = \frac{-a}{z^2}\,dz
$$

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate $$ z  \tan \theta  = a \tag{1} $$ 
$$ dz \tan \theta  +  z  \sec ^2\theta\; d\theta = 0 \tag{2}$$
$$ \dfrac{d \theta }{dz}=\dfrac{-\tan\theta \cos^2 \theta}{z}= \dfrac{(-a/z) \cos^2 \theta}{z}=\dfrac{-a \cos^2 \theta}{z^2} \tag{3}.$$
and re-arrange.